# Clarification on EM Algorithm

Tags: maximum-likelihood, expectation-maximization, marginal-distribution

So the general set-up for the EM algorithm is the following recursion
\begin{align}
\theta^{(t+1)}&=\text{argmax}_\theta\sum_zp(z\;|\;x,\theta^{(t)})\log\frac{p(x,z\;|\;\theta)}{p(z\;|\;x,\theta^{(t)})}\\
&=\text{H}(Z\;|\;X,\theta^{(t)}) + \frac{1}{p(x\;|\;\theta^{(t)})}\text{argmax}_\theta\sum_zp(x,z\;|\;\theta^{(t)})\log p(x,z\;|\;\theta),
\end{align}

where the expression increases monotonically towards a lower bound for $\log p(x\;|\;\hat{\theta})$.

However in the latter formulation, we see that our problem doesn't require us to compute 
$$p(x\;|\;\theta^{(t)})=\sum_zp(x,z\;|\;\theta^{(t)}).$$

So my question is, when we perform EM in order to find a point estimate of $\theta$ which approximates the marginal MLE, is it standard practice to run the algorithm on
$$\theta^{(t+1)}=\text{argmax}_\theta\sum_zp(x,z\;|\;\theta^{(t)})\log p(x,z\;|\;\theta),$$
and then once it converges to a (possibly only local) maxima, then if we want an estimate for $p(z\;|\;x,\hat{\theta})$ or $p(x\;|\;\hat{\theta})$ we use $\theta^*\approx\hat{\theta}$ in order to compute it?

Comment: @Xi'an as far as I can tell it's correct, and the algorithm I wrote based on it works.

Comment: the reference I'm basing this off of is http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~awm/10701/assignments/EM.pdf, with (11) being basically the exact recursion I present.

Comment: $E_{z|x,\theta^{(t)}}[\log p(x,z|\theta)]=\frac{1}{p(x\;|\;\theta^{(t)})}\sum_zp(x,z|\;\theta^{(t)})\log p(x,z\;|\;\theta)$ and then I take the argmax of this with respect to theta, so basically I combined the E and M steps into a single recursion.

Comment: ya sorry I guess it's not the standard set-up, I'm just trying to dig down into the nitty-gritty so I know the best way to code it.

Comment: The EM algorithm converges to a value that is a local maximum so it is either exactly the MLE or something else that cannot be really considered as an approximation. For the original question, I would say it is less customary to compute the summation over the joint because it seems easier to handle a conditional expectation. You get the same outcome anyway and I do not know of a case when this would improve things.

Comment: I fear there may be some simplification in the E step which I'm missing then.  As far as I understand it you have the joint $p(x,z|\theta^{(t)})$ immediately at your disposal for each iteration, but you don't have $p(z|x,\theta^{(t)})$ unless you compute $p(x|\theta^{(t)})$ for each iteration, which isn't necessary since it doesn't depend on $\theta$.  So why compute it if you don't need to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second decomposition of the EM objective function is quite correct and hence maximising one expression or another leads to the same update. Most often, however, the solution $\theta^{(n)}$ will appear as an expectation under the conditional distribution  $p(z\;|\;x,\theta^{(t)})$. Check for instance the resolution of the Gaussian estimation problem on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm#Gaussian_mixture): all updates are conditional expectations.

Comment: now I get it, the expectation $E_{z|x,\theta^{(t)}}[\log p(x_i,z_i|\theta)]$ reduces to $E_{z_i|x_i,\theta^{(t)}}[\log p(x_i,z_i|\theta)]$, which makes the conditional expectation tractable for large $N$.

Answer (score 1):

As a contribution, you might have situations where you are not receiving all the samples at once at each EM iteration.

To have a good estimate of the hyperparameters $\theta$, you would need all the samples which is not always the case in one iteration. For instance, you might perform a Stochastic Gradient Descent to update $\theta$, in which case the E step has to be update in a different manner as well.

You can find out more in Cappé and Moulines' [work](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0712.4273.pdf)